# How to make the Unity Launcher to be transparent?

Tags: unity, launcher

How to make the Unity Launcher to be transparent ?

Comment: I'm assuming this question is for either 10.10's Netbook Edition or 11.04.

Answer (score 3):

You can't but you can make the top panel transparent.

Answer (score 2):

Testing Ubuntu 11.10 I see that the launcher and the top bars can be configured to be transparent using ccsm. So the problem will be solved with the next Ubuntu version.

Comment: And so it has...at least for the 3D version of Unity, anyway.

Answer (score -1):

U can make the top panel transparent using compiz setting manager.
Compizconfig Setting Manager ---->ubuntu unity plugin ---> experimental tab.