# Customizing Unity Launcher with Launcher.qml

Tags: launcher

I have been customizing the /usr/share/unity-2d/launcher/Launcher.qml file so that the Launcher will be completely transparent.  However, every time I save it and do unity --replace nothing changes.  I found that if I run unity-2d-launcher it loads a new launcher above the one that loads after unity --replace and the new launcher is transparent, however the old one is still there.  This leads me to believe that the launcher is now part of a separate process or something because if I look at my running processes after startup unity-2d-launcher isn't there.  I REALLY want to remove that background from my launcher.  Can someone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`unity --replace` starts Unity 3D - effectively you will be running both Unity-2D and Unity-3D at the same time.

If you are making changes to the `launcher.qml` file, logout and login to the Ubuntu-2D session for your changes to take effect.

If you post in your question what changes you made to the `launcher.qml` file, it would be very useful to others who what to also make the launcher transparent.

Comment: thank you for your post, I don't think I explained my problem thoroughly enough.  I'm currently running unity 3D so the Unity 3D launcher is showing up.  If I login to Unity 2D my changes are there, however I want to change these settings in Unity 3D.  Is that just not possible?

Comment: in that case your question is really a duplicate of this (http://askubuntu.com/questions/35951/how-to-make-the-unity-launcher-to-be-transparent) -  and according to that answer, no not possible in unity 3D.

Answer (score 1):

After customizing the file, you have two simple options:

- Log in and log out. That will start Unity 2D's components (yes, they are separate programs in Unity 2D) from scratch.
- Run: `killall unity-2d-launcher` and then run `unity-2d-launcher`. You can do this from the run dialogue (if you do it in a terminal you will need to use `nohup` before the commands or `& disown` after them.